# Save elements in bidimensional array

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

How can i save numbers in a two dimensional array? Why this code doesn't work?

```
void input_arr(int *arr, int n, int m);

void print_arr(int *arr, int n, int m);

int main()
{
    int *arr;
    int n, m;

    printf("Insert line of array: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    printf("Insert column of array: ");
    scanf("%d", &m);

    arr = calloc(n * m, sizeof(int));

    input_arr(arr, n, m);

    return 0;
}

void input_arr(int *arr, int n, int m)
{
    int i;
    int j;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            printf("Insert element in line %d and column %d: ", i, j);
            scanf("%d", (&arr[i][j]));
        }
    }
}

void print_arr(int *arr, int n, int m)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", *arr[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the code that calls the function. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: That's because `int *arr` is not a type that represents a 2D array (or even something that behaves like a 2D array). Are you actually passing a 2D array to the function? Please provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, please define "doesn't work" - compile error? crash? incorrect values? what?

Comment: @Boninissimo For me the function works!:) It seems you are incorrectly using the function.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow The function cannot work, at least not in a defined behaviour. He is using a double index [i][j] on a single level pointer.

Comment: @DarkAtom And what? He may use the operators for such an array. No problem!

Comment: I updated it with my whole code

Comment: @VladfromMoscow You didn't even try to compile the code. You cannot index an int* with 2 subscripts. Try it and get the error for yourself.

Comment: @kaylum I am sorry. I though that the parameter is declared like int *arr[]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing a pointer to allocated space, this is stored  as if it were a linear array, to do what you want, a 2D array, or something that can be used in the same fashion, you need:

1. An array of pointers for lines and allocate memory for each one of them simulating columns.
2. Double pointer and allocate memory to store values in a way that emulates lines and columns.
3. You could also use the linear array and make the inputs and ouputs seem like it's a 2D array.
4. Or you can just use a plain normal 2D array.

Since you are using memory allocation [here is a possible implementation](https://repl.it/@anastaciu/DirectFlickeringHardware) using double pointer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void input_arr(int **arr, int n, int m); //double pointer to int parameter
void print_arr(int **arr, int n, int m); //same

int main() {

    int n, m;
    int **arr; //double pointer for 2D array like memory allocation

    printf("Insert line of array: ");

    if(scanf("%d", &n) != 1 || n < 1) {  //always check input
        puts("positive integer value expected!"); 
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Insert column of array: ");

    if(scanf("%d", &m) != 1 || m < 1) {  //always check input
        puts("positive integer value expected!");
        return 1;
    }

    if(!(arr = malloc(n * sizeof(*arr)))){ //allocate memory lines, check for errors
        perror("Memory allocation failed!");
        return 1;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if(!(arr[i] = malloc(m * sizeof(**arr)))) { //allocate memory for columns, check for errors
            perror("Memory allocation failed");
            return 1;
        }

    input_arr(arr, n, m);
    print_arr(arr, n, m);

    return 0;
}

void input_arr(int **arr, int n, int m) {

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            printf("Insert element in line %d and column %d: ", i, j);
            scanf("%d", &arr[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

void print_arr(int **arr, int n, int m) {

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            printf("%d ", arr[i][j]); //no dereferencing
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
```

Comment: This may be what OP wants/needs, yet `char **arr` is not a 2D array.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, you are correct, it wasn't my intention to imply it, I edited the answer to clarify it.

Comment: Ok i used your solution but can you explain me why i need double pointer **arr? And why to allocate memory i don't have to write sizeof(int) but sizeof(*arr) and sizeof(**arr)?

Comment: Sure @Boninissimo, so in `arr = malloc(n * sizeof(*arr)` I´m allocating memory for an array of pointers, (lines if you will), each one of these pointers will be pointing to the beggining of each line, then in `for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) if(!(arr[i] = malloc(m * sizeof(**arr)...` I'm allocating memory for each one of these lines.  `sizeof(*arr)` is the same as `sizeof(int*)`, meaning the size of a pointer to `int`, I'm allocating memory for each one of these pointers. `sizeof(**arr)` is the same as `sizeof(int)`, I'm allocating memory for all the `int`s in the line.

Comment: Why am I doing it like that, inagine you now want to change your code and you want an array of `double`s, you would need to change all of the `sizeofs` and if you forget one of them your program would fail with no errors because malloc would still work fine, but the allocated space would be too small for your needs, with this construct you just need to change the declaration of `arr` from `int` to `double` and everything would work fine.

Comment: This will allow you to use the array notation like before, `arr[i][j]` with the advantage that you are now working with allocated memory avoiding the stack size issues. I know it might be a lot to take in so let me know if you still have some doubts.

Comment: I got it!! Thank you @anastaciu

Answer (score 1):

Replace your function declarations like so:

```
void input_arr(int *arr[], int n, int m)
void print_arr(int *arr[], int n, int m)
```

Wherever you have `scanf` and `printf` calls for the array elements, use this:

```
scanf("%d", arr + i * m + j);
printf("%d", *(arr + i * m + j));
```

For good practice, free your memory when you are done with it. Add this at the end of your `main()`:

```
free(arr);
```

Also, if you have a C99 or later compiler, you can use **variable-length arrays** to do the job and allow you to index the array with `arr[i][j]` instead of the ugly `arr + i * m + j`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//note that the arr parameter must be declared AFTER the m parameter since it uses its information
void input_arr(int n, int m, int arr[][m]);

void print_arr(int n, int m, int arr[][m]);

int main(void)
{
    int n, m;

    printf("Insert line of array: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    printf("Insert column of array: ");
    scanf("%d", &m);

    int arr[n][m];

    input_arr(n, m, arr);

    print_arr(n, m, arr); //I am assuming you also want to print the array

    //return 0; //not needed in C99
}

void input_arr(int n, int m, int arr[][m])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            printf("Insert element in line %d and column %d: ", i, j);
            scanf("%d", &arr[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

void print_arr(int n, int m, int arr[][m])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", arr[i][j]);
        }
        //you probably want a new line here to display it as a matrix
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code allocates and initializes a contiguous chunk of memory and passes a pointer to `int` to the functions. The problem is that inside those function, that pointer is dereferenced too many times.

```
void input_arr(int *arr, int n, int m)
{
    // ...
    scanf("%d", (&arr[i][j]));
    //                  ^^^ 
}

void print_arr(int *arr, int n, int m)
{
    // ...
    printf("%d ", *arr[i][j]);
    //            ^      ^^^
}
```

If you can use variable length arrays, a different option from the ones already posted in the other answers is to declare a pointer to a VLA inside those function:

```
void input_arr(int *arr, int n, int m)
{
    // ...
    scanf("%d", arr++);
    //          ^^^ Here you can just access to every element in order 
}

void print_arr(int *arr, int n, int m)
{
    // Declare a pointer to array of m elements
    int (*mat)[m] = (void *)arr;

    // ...
    printf("%d ", mat[i][j]);
    //            ^^^^^^^^^  Use it as if it's a 2D VLA
}
```

Also, remember to free the allocated memory in `main`.

Answer (score 0):

> How can i save numbers in a two dimensional array?

Example:

```
int twoD[2][3];
twoD[1][1] = 42;
```

> Why this code doesn't work?

OP's code is not using a 2D array, but a pointer to `int` and then incorrectly uses that pointer.

```
int *arr;
// Allocate memory for a 1-D array of  n*m `int` 
arr = calloc(n * m, sizeof(int));
```

Function code attempts to de-reference an `int`

```
void input_arr(int *arr, int n, int m) {
  ...
  scanf("%d", (&arr[i][j])); // bad
```

Here `arr[i]` is an `int`. `arr[i][j]` makes no sense.

---

To allocate memory you need a pointer, but what type?

Do you want a pointer to a 2D array, below,
a pointer to an array of `int [m]` [DarkAtom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61433730/2410359)
or a pointer to an array of pointers to `int` [@anastaciu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61433842/2410359)?

```
int (*TwoD)[m][n] = malloc(sizeof *Two);
(*TwoD)[1][1] = 42;
....
```

Or use current code in a 2D-like way and access the 1D array allocation with a computed index.

```
// scanf("%d", (&arr[i][j]));
scanf("%d", &arr[i*m + j]);

// printf("%d ", *arr[i][j]);
printf("%d ", arr[i*m + j]);
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to pass the array as a double pointer (int **array or simpler int *array[]).

**Explanation**
By passing the array as int* array, when you say &array[i] you are inferring to the copied value of the array and not the original value.
Specifically, in a function, when you just want to read (or/and print) array data you can simply use single pointer but if you want to change it, you have to use double pointer.

Comment: That will work, but the caller code might need to be modified too (depending on how the array is declared).

Comment: Yes that is correct, though there is no way around it

Comment: Your explanation however is wrong. The reason you need a double pointer is because it is a bidimentional array. The function can ALWAYS modify the contents of the caller's array unless it is a `const` parameter, because the array is passed by it's address.